# Why can't I get the 'Add' and 'Clear' methode of IList from RTTI

Tags: delphi, deserialization, spring4d

I have an interface `IList<T>` (from `Spring.Collections`) that I want to deserialize with MVCFrameWork. It does not work, because in the code we have a function `IsWrap()` that looks if the methods `Add()` and `Clear()` exist, but the RTTI for `IList` does not include those methods.

Some code:

```
TPerson = class (TInterfacedObject)
private
  fLastName: String;
  fFirstName: String;
public
  property FirstName: String read fFirstName write fFirstName;
  property LastName: String read fLastName write fLastName;
end;

implementation

uses
  Generics.Collections,
  Spring.Collections,
  MVCFramework.Serializer.Intf,
  MVCFramework.Serializer.JsonDataObjects;

procedure TSerializerTest.JsonToCollection;
begin
  var strJson: string := '[{"FirstName": "Ricardo", "LastName": "The killer" }, {"FirstName": "Zorro", "LastName": "Z-Man" }]';
  var oPersons : IList<TPerson> := TCollections.CreateObjectList<TPerson> ;
  //  var oPersons : TList<TPerson> := TList<TPerson>.Create ;
  //  var oPersons : TObjectList<TPerson> := TObjectList<TPerson>.Create() ;
  var lSerializer: IMVCSerializer := TMVCJsonDataObjectsSerializer.Create;

  lSerializer.DeserializeCollection(strJson, oPersons, TPerson);

  Assert.AreEqual(oPersons[0].FirstName , 'Ricardo');
  Assert.AreEqual(oPersons[1].FirstName , 'Zorro');
end;
```

`TList<TPerson>` and `TObjectList<TPerson>` work.

`IList<TPerson>` does not work, because we can not find the methods `Add()` and `Clear()` with the RTTI.

```
procedure TSerializerTest.CheckAddAndClearRTTI;
var
  ObjectType: TRttiType;
  FContext: TRttiContext;
begin 
  var oPersons : IList<TPerson> := TCollections.CreateObjectList<TPerson> ;

  //METHODE ADD AND CLEAR EXIST 
  oPersons.Add(TPerson.Create);  
  oPersons.Clear;

  ObjectType := FContext.GetType(oPersons.AsObject.ClassInfo);
  if (ObjectType.GetMethod('Add') <> nil) and (ObjectType.GetMethod('Clear') <> nil)  then
  begin 
    ShowMessage('Is List');  // DOES NOT GET HERE, WHY
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are not accessing the RTTI of the `IList` itself, you are accessing the RTTI of the object that backs the `IList`. I don't know how Spring is implemented, but my guess is that the backing object simply doesn't have those methods available, it probably maps them to different names (see [Method Resolution Clause](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Method_Resolution_Clause)). Did you try using the object's RTTI to enumerate the actual methods it does have?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are using Spring4D 2.0 because in 1.2 the interfaces inherited from `IInvokable` which gave them method RTTI by default.

However, in 2.0 this has changed and neither the interfaces nor the objects backing them emit any enhanced RTTI simply because the interfaces don't inherit from `IInvokable` anymore nor have `{$M+}` added to them, and in the implementing classes all enhanced RTTI is turned off via the `$RTTI` clause. This is by design and to avoid causing lots of unnecessary binary bloat.

Knowing that one of the major usages of using RTTI on collections is serialization Spring4D offers another approach:

Lists and many other collection types support the non-generic `ICollection` interface from `Spring.Collections` which internally creates a wrapper object around the generic collection and exposes functionality from `IEnumerable` and the `Add(const value: TValue)` and `Clear` methods.

```
var persons := TCollections.CreateObjectList<TPerson>;

var coll := persons as ICollection;
coll.Add(TPerson.Create);
coll.Clear;
```

I have quickly looked into the DMVC code and I can say that they are handling interfaces in a poor way by simply casting them to object and passing that down. I don't know if they have some extension point for customizing serialization but this needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stefan and Remy.

In DMVC I can make a custom serialization

```
  TListSerializer = class(TInterfacedObject, IMVCTypeSerializer)
  public
    procedure SerializeAttribute(const AElementValue: TValue; const APropertyName: string;const ASerializerObject: TObject; const AAttributes: System.TArray<System.TCustomAttribute>);
    procedure SerializeRoot(const AObject: TObject; out ASerializerObject: TObject;const AAttributes: System.TArray<System.TCustomAttribute>;const ASerializationAction: TMVCSerializationAction = nil);
    procedure DeserializeAttribute(var AElementValue: TValue; const APropertyName: string; const ASerializerObject: TObject; const AAttributes: System.TArray<System.TCustomAttribute>);
    procedure DeserializeRoot(const ASerializerObject: TObject; const AObject: TObject;const AAttributes: System.TArray<System.TCustomAttribute>);
  end;
```

And I registered to Serializer

```
  var lSerializer: IMVCSerializer := TMVCJsonDataObjectsSerializer.Create;
  lSerializer.RegisterTypeSerializer(TypeInfo(TFoldedList<System.TObject>), TListSerializer.Create);
```

`IList<TPerson>` is a `TFoldedList<System.TObject>`

Comment: Good for you that it works for now but this approach is just asking to fail the next time something internally changes - their serialization mechanism really should not work on the object behind the interface but on the interface itself.